# data and salt arguments are required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, express

(node:35) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and salt arguments required.

THis is the error i am getting please can anyone help me how to solve this

```
const validatePassword = (password) => {
  return password.length > 4;
};

app.post("/register", async (request, response) => {
  const {
    username,
    name,
    email,
    password,
    gender,
    location,
    mobileNumber,
  } = request.body;
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  const selectUserQuery = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '${username}';`;
  // const dbUser = await db.get(selectUserQuery);
  if (selectUserQuery.length > 0) {
    const createUserQuery = `
      INSERT INTO 
        user (username, name, email,password, gender, location,mobileNumber) 
      VALUES 
        (
          '${username}', 
          '${name}',
          '${email}',
          '${hashedPassword}', 
          '${gender}',
          '${location}',
          '${mobileNumber}'
        )`;
    if (validatePassword(password)) {
      // await db.run(createUserQuery);
      console.log(createUserQuery);
      response.send("User created successfully");
    } else {
      response.status(400);
      response.send("Password is too short");
    }
  } else {
    response.status(400);
    response.send("User already exists");
  }
});
```

(node:35) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and salt arguments required.

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide a salt to hash the password:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
    });
});
```

So this line `const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);`

Should be:

```
// generate salt to hash password
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    
// now we set user password to hashed password
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
```

More info here: [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

Comment: how to modify above code

Comment: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/register" host=sowedane-app.herokuapp.com request_id=25801e29-70e9-4c5f-ad6a-ae3c4c096d9b fwd="103.224.159.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: (node:35) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and salt arguments required 
  at /app/app.js:54:39

Comment: I have applied but not resolving

Comment: What line is this (`/app/app.js:54:39`) in your code?

Comment: while checking with app.http code is correct but when deployed to heroku it is showing the error

Comment: const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt); this is 54:39

Comment: Then maybe it is a problem with heroku. Because that is how you should hash passwords. See here for an example: https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/hashing-user-passwords-using-bcryptjs/

Comment: please mention some sites  where i can deploy my backend i.e for node js

Comment: I use DigitalOcean. But heroku should work just fine. Here is a tutorial on how to deploy a nodejs app on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs